# Setting to prevent <c-h> to erase text

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, insert-mode, iterm2, ascii

I have a map which allows me to navigate with hjkl in insert mode:

```
" In insert or command mode, move normally by using Ctrl
inoremap <C-h> <Left>
inoremap <C-j> <Down>
inoremap <C-k> <Up>
inoremap <C-l> <Right>
cnoremap <C-h> <Left>
cnoremap <C-j> <Down>
cnoremap <C-k> <Up>
cnoremap <C-l> <Right>
```

All maps works, except `<c-h>`. In insert mode, when a I press `<c-h>`, backspace occours.
I know that `^H` is the ASCII for backspace, but I would like to know if there's some way to make my `<c-h>` works as `<left>`.

When I run: `:verbose inoremap <c-h>` it returns

```
i  <C-H>       *@<C-R>=AutoPairsDelete()<CR>                                                                                                                            │ost/site/content/themes/sc5
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/auto-pairs/plugin/auto-pairs.vim line 549                                                                                          │0k/gulpfile.js
i  <C-H>       * <Left>                                                                                                                                                 │[10:29:37] Starting 'watch'
        Last set from ~/.dotfiles/nvim/init.vim line 264
```

A courious thing is that in `command mode`, `<c-h>` works fine!

I'm using iTerm2 in MacOS Catalina with tmux and neovim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to your output of `verbose inoremap <c-h>` it's really easy to see what is happening here!

You are using the [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) plug-in and it's installing buffer-local mappings for the bracket keys, but also for keys such as Enter and Backspace. It maps backspace so it can "undo" a close bracket action if you type backspace to erase a mistake of yours.

Now, there's actually a difference between `<C-h>` and "backspace". While historically the backspace key would produce the `<C-h>` sequence, that's no longer the case and most modern terminal emulators will produce a different sequence for the "backspace" key (unless they're configured to produce the `<C-h>` sequence for backward compatibility reasons, but that's more and more rare nowadays.)

For historical reasons, auto-pairs (and probably most other plug-ins that map backspace) will by default map `<C-h>` *as well as* "backspace", so that if you have an old terminal or have it misconfigured, everything will keep working the same with `<C-h>` as it does with the "backspace" key.

(It's true that the default action of Vim for `<C-h>` is the same as backspace, for much of the same reasons.)

Fortunately, auto-pairs allows you to control these two mappings individually, by setting global variables from your vimrc, you have `g:AutoPairsMapBS` to create the mapping for the backspace key, and `g:AutoPairsMapCh` to create the mapping for `<C-h>`.

So you can fix your issue simply by adding this line to your vimrc file:

```
let g:AutoPairsMapCh = 0
```

Comment: Hello @filbranden, tks your great explanation and the solution. You helped my productivity a lot! Greetings from Brazil!

Comment: @DiegoSomar Bem-vindo ao site do Vim! Tem alguns outros brasileiros por aqui, de repente fundamos um site em português também! 

Comment: Muito bom saber disso! :)

Comment: This saves my day. The plugin is exactly the culprit in my case.